# How to sort array data before inserting into the mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

[image]

i have a form like this below

```
<form action="route('docaluculation')" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="number" name="student_score_number[]">
  <input type="number" name="student_score_number[]">
  <input type="number" name="student_score_number[]">
  <input type="number" name="student_score_number[]">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

when the form is submitted it only inserts then number, i want it to get the numbers foreach number and kind of sort them and grade them accordingly.

In my image below, id 1,2 and 10 should have 1st position which is "1", then id 3 should have 2nd position which is 2, etc. Ive tried what i can do but i dont even know how to do it, im using query builder pls, i have read on for loops and php arrays but i dont know where to start

Comment: its a normal thing, we are all learning :)

Comment: you can do this using sql only, its a little bit complex

Comment: @madalinivascu thank you, how can i do it, i was thinking maybe i could use foreach to get all the numbers and then maybe sort of store it some where, rank them and then insert them into the database, but i dont know how that'll work, any ideas

Comment: That doesn't make sense: When you enter new data, positions may change so you'd have to re-calculate your whole database. Instead calculate and display the position when you need it.

Comment: Laravel offers a helper function to sort arrays: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-sort

Comment: @AndréLuizdeGusmão and jeroen thanks so much, both your answers are very helpful and works hand in hand, it worked perfectly.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek thank you too. I see youre looking for a job on your profile, i hope you find one, im off to MY job, bye

Answer (score 1):

Like this in any controller,

```
use App\YourNumbersModel;

public function sortNumbers(){

    $groupedNumbers = YourNumbersModel::get()->orderBy('number', 'desc')->groupBy('number');

    $i = 1;

    foreach($groupedNumbers as $gp){
      foreach($gp as $numberToSort){

        $DBnumber = YourNumbersModel::where('id', $numberToSort->id)->first();

        $DBnumber->position = $i;

        $DBnumber->save();
     }
     $i++;
    }

}
```

edit: Just coded this here, if you have any question you can ask me, hope you understand what I'm doing

for doing it before inserting you can use quite the same algorithm

```
public function sortNumbers($userInput){

      $groupedNumbers = collect($userInput); //collect the request input with laravel eloquent

      $groupedNumbers = $groupedNumbers->orderBy('number', 'desc')->groupBy('number');


      foreach($groupedNumbers as $gp){
          foreach($gp as $numberToSort){

            $DBnumber = YourNumbersModel::where('id', $numberToSort->id)->first();

            $DBnumber->position = $i;

            $DBnumber->save();
         }
         $i++;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use rank as position

```
SET @rank=0;
    select rank,score from (select @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank,score 
    from  survey  
    order by score desc) as t2
```

Comment: how can i do it with query builder

Comment: Run these two queries in different functions
$this->db->query('SET @rank=0');
$this->db->query('select rank,score from (select @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank,score 
    from  survey  
    order by score desc) as t2');

Answer (score 0):

Try to sort before the database

```
$scores = sort($request->input('student_score_number'));
```